# Error deploying WSP package

Tags: deployment, feature

Error: Cannot find this file specified in the manifest file: ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.dll

I'm getting this error when attempting to deploy this solution to the Sharepoint environment. 
Here is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
   SolutionId="F9850E13-81B6-47E1-BBC6-42AC70A903C3" >
  <FeatureManifests>
     <FeatureManifest Location="List\Feature.xml"/>
  </FeatureManifests>
  <Assemblies>
     <Assembly DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" Location="ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.dll"/>
  </Assemblies>
</Solution>
```

Here is my deploy.ddf:

```
.OPTION Explicit ; Generate errors
.Set DiskDirectory1="..\bin"
.Set CabinetNameTemplate="ChangeContentType.wsp"

manifest.xml
.Set DestinationDir="List\ListTemplates"
List\ListTemplates\ListManifest.xml ; specify cab file name
.Set DestinationDir="List\Messages"
List\Messages\schema.xml
.Set DestinationDir="List"
List\Feature.xml
..\bin\ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.dll ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.dll
```

I have confirmed that ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.dll is in the bin folder above the Source folder where the manifest.xml and deploy.ddf files exist.

Any suggestions or reasons why my deployment is unable to find this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DLL needs to be at the same level as the manifest.xml inside your WSP (ie: the root level).

Looks like it's ending up in the "List" folder at the minute.

Comment: I think you may be right James, but how to change the code to do this?  I was under the impression that the following line [..\bin\ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.dll ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.dll] would find the file in the bin directory of my project

Comment: Your `.Set DestinationDir` is confusing it. Try `.Set DestinationDir=.` (with just a dot at the end) just before the line where you declare your dll in the bin dir (but only declare it once).

Comment: That worked.  Now I'm getting an issue with the runtime version.  Thanks for your help again today, James!

Comment: No worries dude :)